# Assign value using loop in HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, haml

My question is kind of a general ruby question, but I'm using HAML so I'll ask it in that context.

I'm using twitter bootstrap and I want to iterate over a list to populate a popover's content

I have:

```
    %div 
      =link_to link_name, link, ..., "data-content" => <my_content_here>
```

and I want to put something like the following into the data content. I've tried partials, but can't seem to get anything to work

```
    %div
      f.item.each do |t|
        .myclass=t
```

Comment: can you explain what you want in your output? and on which item you want to loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HAML**

```
%div
 - f.item.each do |t| 
   = link_to link_name, link, ..., data: {content: your_content}, class: t
```

You'll benefit from reading up on the [HAML docs](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html)

You basically just need to indent for each code bock; your `div` being a block & your `. each` loop being a block

The main thing you need to remember is that `=` is equal to `<%=` | `-` is equal to `<%`